# SQL Database: Locking a list of financial transactions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on an application that will have a table of financial transactions associated with users, with a column indicating the change to their total balance. Is there a way to add a restriction so that the table will not accept a transaction that would result in the user's total balance being less than 0, without having to lock the whole table?

If I were to store the calculated balance separately, I think I could achieve this restriction by just locking that row in the balances table as a part of a transaction that both adds the new financial transaction and updates the balance, but I think this kind of "calculated" table is frowned upon as it can get out of sync with the actual source of truth. Is there a way to avoid such an approach?

Comment: You can't be really computing the balance every time you insert, update, or delete a transaction. You need to keep a running balance somewhere for performance reasons. In order to keep integrity of it, you can use pre-insert, pre-update, and pre-delete triggers. Now to keep performance under multi-threaded scenarios, you can avoid row locking by using the row version number pattern; this way your DML statements will be blazing fast all the while they keep your constraints validated at all times. Good question, by the way. +1